# Soft Credits Section Does Not Load

Tags: forms, soft-credit

When I try to add an offline contribution the soft credits portion of the screen shows a PHP Warning rather than the fields for the soft credit. [image: soft credits forms section only shows PHP warning]

The warning is

> Warning: Undefined array key "siteHasPCPs" in
> /var/www/private_fs/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%6F/6F7/6F7BB438%%Contribution.tpl.php
> on line 378

The only solution I have found is changing line 378.

The line I have is  `<?php if ($this->_tpl_vars['siteHasPCPs']  && ! $this->_tpl_vars['payNow']): ?>`

If I add `?? NULL` after `$this->_tpl_vars['siteHasPCPs']` the line becomes  `<?php if ($this->_tpl_vars['siteHasPCPs'] ?? NULL  && ! $this->_tpl_vars['payNow']): ?>`

This change makes the form load as expected.  [image: CiviCRM Soft Credit section loading as expected]

Before making changes to the code I tried flushing the caches and deletting the templates so that CiviCRM can regenerate them. For each of these attempts I get no change to the issue.

I am running CiviCRM 5.59.3 with Drupal 9.5.5.

I think this was happening before the upgrade but I cannot be positive.  I Googled with some different terms this morning and found an issue related to this on the CiviCRM GitLab instance.  https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4006#register-pane

If I get an answer there I will update this question.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[This fix](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4006#register-pane) on GitLab solves the problem for this specific file. I found other places that this is happening and I will need to work on those on their own.